# EXCEL formula to count number of times each value appears in column for each unique IDs in another column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table of data below in columns A & B. I would like to count the number of times a Type number appears for each ID shown in the top table D to I. I've included the answers I'm looking for in the table under it.

I know I can use =COUNTIFS(B2:B25,"="&E1) to get the count of the Types, but I don't know how to make them unique to each unique ID

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just left out the other part of the `COUNTIFS`.

Try: `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$25, E$1, $A$2:$A$25, $D2)`

Comment: That works, except for the blanks, but i can work on that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$25, IF(E$1="Blank","",E$1), $A$2:$A$25, $D2)
```